# Partial sums involving Gregory coefficients that cannot be an integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divisors-multiples

For integers $n\geq 1$ let $G_n$ be the Gregory coefficients or reciprocal logarithmic numbers, see the Wikipedia [*Gregory coefficients.*]
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients) 
$${z\over\log(1+z)}=1+\sum_1^{\infty}G_nz^n$$ 
I think that I was inspired in [1] to ask the question.

> **Question.** Let $1\leq N<M$ where $N$ and $M$ are integers. Is it possible to determine examples of a choice of integers $0\leq \alpha,\beta,\gamma$ for which $$\sum_{k=N}^M k^{\alpha}2^{\beta k}k!^{\gamma}|G_k|$$
>   is never an integer for all $N$ and $M$? **Many thanks.**

I suspect of some simple example from a few computations that I did with a Pari/GP program. I would like to know some case(s) with a good mathematical content. In your examples you can take some of those exponents $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or $\gamma$ equals to zero, but the case $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$ is excluded in this disccussion.

### References:

[1] Thomas J. Osler, *Partial sums of series that cannot be an integer*, The Mathematical Gazette Vol. 96, No. 537 (November 2012), pp. 515-519.

Comment: Feel free to add feedback about if the question is interesting, or if it is possible do some work about it.

Comment: **Unrelated to my post** is that I am trying to think other problems involving $\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}|G_k|x^k$, for example diophantine equations similar than some that are in the literature or study the norms or zeros of these polynomials, $\sum_{1\leq k\leq k}|G_k|x^k=0$, but currently I have no ideas for interesting problems that involve these quantities.

Comment: Many thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: Next time, maybe you'll do it yourself.